# How do i pass parameters to JavaScript function via out.print in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp

My JavaScript function is:

```
function f1(name){
    alert("Hello "+name);
}
```

My JSP code is:

```
<% out.print("<button onclick='f1(Rahul)'>Click me</button>"); %>
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: i m not being able to call the function f1() with parameter:'Rahul'

Comment: is `Rahul` the name of a JSP variable or a request parameter?

Comment: just a string parameter: 'Rahul'

Comment: Then it is not a parameter... Just escape it using `"`. Also, since you're already in JSP, you should directly write the HTML instead of printing it inside a scriptlet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Rahul` is a plain `String` you want/need to pass it as parameter, you should escape it with quotes (") by using backslash (\) character:

```
<% out.print("<button onclick='f1(\"Rahul\")'>Click me</button>"); %>
                                  ^escape the quote
```

Still, since you're already in JSP, you don't need to write the HTML code inside scriptlet, so you can change this to:

```
<%
    ...whatever code is here, probably a loop (very strange, indeed)
%>
    <button onclick='f1("Rahul")'>Click me</button>
<%
    rest of your scriptlet code...
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape sequences (\) to do such jobs!
Try this:

```
<% out.print("<button onclick='f1(\"Rahul\")'>Click me</button>"); %>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer and up-vote! so that other people can find it easily!